# Accessing Hidden Folders with FilePicker

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Im trying to gain access to a file in the Users AppData folders. I've resigned myself to the fact that I'll have to use FilePicker and FutureAccess to get this done. My problem is that the FilePicker wont show hidden folders. Anyone got a solution for this?

Cheers
Ross